# sweetalert not working in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have used SweetAlert for showing alerts of validation and the code is below however its not working properly only in firefox. The alertbox starts appearing and then disappears and Javascript is bascially hung from that point. The code is as follows:

jQuery('.enroll-button').click(function (e) {

```
e.preventDefault();

var l = Ladda.create(this);

var tLeadType = jQuery('input[name="radioOpt"]:checked', '#sellBuyOpt').val()
var nSourceId = 0;

<?php if (isset($_GET["nsourceid"])){
    echo 'nSourceId = '.$_GET["nsourceid"];
} ?>

var inputElements = [];

var tFirstName = jQuery("#firstName");
var tLastName = jQuery("#lastName");
var tEmailAddress = jQuery("#email");
var tCity = jQuery("#city");
var tState = jQuery("#state");
var tPhoneNumber = jQuery("#phoneNumber");

inputElements.push(tFirstName);
inputElements.push(tLastName);
inputElements.push(tEmailAddress);
inputElements.push(tCity);
inputElements.push(tState);
inputElements.push(tPhoneNumber);


//validations
var validated = true;

for(var i= 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){

    if(inputElements[i].val().trim()===""){
        inputElements[i].val("");
        inputElements[i].attr("placeholder","This is required");
        inputElements[i].css("border-color","#A33643");
        validated = false;
    }

    if(i == 2){
        var res = validateEmail(inputElements[i].val());
        if(!res){
            inputElements[i].val("");
            inputElements[i].attr("placeholder","Valid Email required");
            inputElements[i].css("border-color","#A33643");
            validated = false;
        }
    }

    if(i == 4 && inputElements[i].val() == "Select a state"){
        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please select a valid state!", "error");
        validated = false;
    }

    if(i == 5 && !simpleClientPhoneValidator(inputElements[i].val())){
        inputElements[i].val("");
        inputElements[i].attr("placeholder","Invalid Phone Number");
        inputElements[i].css("border-color","#A33643");
        validated = false;
    }
```